# ASP.net MVC Routing for blog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to set up routing for blog, like this:

www.smth.com/news/ -> all news are displayed
www.smth.com/news/admin -> admin panel for news
www.smth.com/news/this-is-a-post-name   -> single post

I've tired it like this but with no luck:

```
    routes.MapRoute("News", "news/{title}",
                new { controller = "News", action = "Post", title = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Post(string title)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "News");

            }

            if (title.ToLower() == "admin")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Admin", "News");
            }

            return View("Single");

        }
```

The error I got is:

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your first route rule is catching things like /news/admin and mapping to your Post() action (with title=admin), so redirecting to /news/admin again, putting you into a loop.